# problem converting input to react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

In developing my client-side auth, I used basic html to set up my login:

```
<div>
  <input
    name="username"
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    placeholder="username"
  />
  <input
    name="password"
    type="password"
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    placeholder="password"
  />
  <button onClick={signIn}>Sign In</button>
</div>
```

But I'm converting the login page to bootstrap and running into a problem with an `onChange` event:

```
function onChangeHandler(event) {
  event.persist();
  console.log(event);
  updateFormState(() => ({
    ...formState,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  }));
}

const { formType } = formState;

async function signIn() {
  try {
    const { username, password } = formState;
    const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
    updateFormState(() => ({ ...formState, formType: 'authenticated' }));
  } catch (errors) {
    alert(errors.message);
  }
}
```

the events log similarly and I can see the `event.target.value` which is in the console.  I think somehow the object id's are colliding with the use of bootstrap's controlId.

This is the bootstrap version:

```
<Form>
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>User Name</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      id="username"
      name="username"
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
      placeholder="Enter username"
    />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      We'll never share your email with anyone else.
    </Form.Text>
    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      id="password"
      name="password"
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
      type="password"
      placeholder="Password"
    />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      <i>forgot password</i>
    </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>
  <Button onClick={signIn} variant="primary" type="submit">
    Sign In
  </Button>
</Form>
```

Comment: I've tried to recreate the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-kowalevski-84p4d?file=/src/App.js. `onChange` seems to be working as expected (see console)

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 it appears that I needed to call `preventDefault()` before `signIn()`.

Comment: the issue is with regards to `signIn`? that was not mentioned in the question - the question mentions the problem to be on `onChange` as I've read it. at least you've solved it

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 yeh, I suppose I wasn't clear on that.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I have to call `preventDefault()`.

```
<Button
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    signIn();
  }}
  variant="primary"
  type="submit"
>
```